# Showing almost-sure convergence, given condition.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space with $X_1,X_2,...:\Omega\to R$ independent random variables. Take $E[X_i]=0$ for all $i\in N$ and
$\sum_i E[X_i^2\cdot \chi_{\{|X_i|\le 1\}} + |X_i|\cdot \chi_{\{|X_i|>1]}]< \infty$

show $\sum_i X_i$ converges $P$- almost everywhere.

I tried splitting the sample space into two - On $\{|X_i|> 1\}$ we can use Kolmogorov's three series theorem - the expectations converge because the sum of the expectations of the absolute values are finite, for example, and the other two series can be shown to converge.
I don't know how to deal with $\{|X_i|> 1\}$. I can't use the theorem which guarantees a.s. convergence given expectations equal to zero and given $\sum_i E[X_i^2]<\infty$, because after restricting the sample space I can't be sure that the expectations are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum X_i \chi_{|X_i| \leq 1}$ converges almost surely by Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem. Note that $\sum EX_i \chi_{|X_i| \leq 1}=-\sum EX_i \chi_{|X_i| > 1}$ since $EX_i=0$ for all $n$. And it is given that $\sum EX_i \chi_{|X_i| > 1}$ is convergent.

Since $\sum E|X_i|\chi_{|X_i| > 1} <\infty$ it follows that $\sum |X_i|\chi_{|X_i| > 1} <\infty$  almost surely. Adding these two series we get almost sure convergence of $\sum X_i$.

Comment: Thank you, but could you give me a hint for the detail? How does it follow from the convergence of the expectations that the random variables converge almost surely?

Comment: It is basic fact from measure theory that if $\sum \int f_n <\infty$ where $f_n$'s are non-negative measurable functions then $\sum f_n$ converges almost everywhere. Proof is by Tonelli's Theorem: if $\sum f_n=\infty$ on some set $E$ of positive measure then $\int \sum f_n =\infty$ and we can interchange the sum and the integral by Tonelli's Theorem. @SvetiIvanRilski

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Where is it then that we use the three series theorem? it seems we just show that for both sets into which we divided the sample space, the sum of the expectations is finite, and so, by the result you mentioned, the sum of the r.v.s is finite.

Comment: @SvetiIvanRilski The measure theoretic argument I used for the second part applies only to non-negative random varibsles. In the first part we cannot use convergence of $\sum EX_i\chi_{|X-i| \leq 1}$ to conclude that $\sum X_i\chi_{|X-i| \leq 1}$ is itself convergent. We need Three Series Theorem here.

Comment: OK, so I can see clearly how we establish the second and third series - the third series (variance) is obvious from the condition in the question, the second series we can establish as you showed, and by noting that the sum of the expectations is less than the sum of the expectation of absolute values (which is what is given). I don't see how we get the first series. I think it's trivial but i'm missing it.

Comment: @SvetiIvanRilski if $Y_i=X_i\chi_{|X_i| \leq 1}$ then $\sum P(|Y_i| >1)$ is convergent because all the terms are $0$!